# Is it possible to script the flow/stages/steps in Azure Pipelines?

Tags: azure, continuous-integration, azure-pipelines

I'm trying to setup Azure Pipelines for a CI setup and I'm using the YAML syntax to get started. However, I was wondering if it is possible to script the flow at "runtime"? Like you can do in Jenkins script: spawn builds etc.

Depending on the commit I want to have a vastly different flow.
This is because I currently have a mono-repo setup with Conan libraries and I want to rebuild the libraries that are necessary depending on the commit, thus the build-flow is not the same for each commit. I want to spawn jobs so I can take advantage of parallel building on several agents.

Answer (score 1):

For your issue ,do you refer to trigger builds based on specified commits? If so, you can trigger builds by adding `tag trigger` in yaml. You can create tags on the commits. If the tag created meets the trigger condition of the `tag trigger` in yaml , then the build will be triggered.

```
trigger:
  tags:
    include:
    - v2.*
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks but that is not really what I'm looking for. I have a mono-repository and my build flow is depending on what is being committed (which modules should be build and in which in order). I can do everything in one step/job but then I loose the ability to build in parallel and spread across several build nodes).

Comment: Hi , Matt  I don't understand the demand in your comment. Can you give a specific explanation? It's better to give a sample in the question.